# journalctl --verify returns faults how do I fix them?

Tags: dual-boot, crash, bug-reporting, read-only

`journalctl --verify` returns the following but I don't know how to fix it. I think these errors may be causing my linux to crash regularly. If anyone could explain how I can fix these errors, in layman's terms please I am not the most experienced linux user sorry!

```
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@7958ba53b52f476bbb0181d7aa31b4a8-0000000000005f11-0005b6b16963ddc9.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@3a879b45ee0d40f28e9de821dfc83a01-000000000002d0d2-0005b91a831ce03e.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@c9eb907d55864799b9c237f317840e83-0000000000025d8f-0005bb17ae301322.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@7958ba53b52f476bbb0181d7aa31b4a8-0000000000006efb-0005b6b2d5cf8451.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005b8b7c85cd6bf-131244777455ad43.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005b8f3d4ba2c61-b0a32e5d67dddc68.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@2be0bd7baaa9496c8c44a16e4a842995-00000000000d08f8-0005b9b751153286.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005bafa834583ab-e3adcde51bb814e8.journal~                             
3f82ef8: Invalid entry item (13/19 offset: 000000                                                                                        
3f82ef8: Invalid object contents: Bad message                                                                                            
File corruption detected at /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005baef88ddde1f-9b6ca82056b7cec1.journal~:3f82ef8 (of 67108864 bytes, 99%).
FAIL: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005baef88ddde1f-9b6ca82056b7cec1.journal~ (Bad message)
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@3a879b45ee0d40f28e9de821dfc83a01-00000000000c2835-0005b9aecd7a2b63.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005bb158fcb0a28-59197e0fd3b9eb8c.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@35b89873de2d46dca7aea6968c063f41-00000000000008ab-0005baae9d60aea4.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@ebc22b8fecf3454083fac4456729ecf3-00000000000a2f0f-0005b96c14b92654.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005bb158d8ebde0-92856efe6cbbe4e7.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005b8b7c47240ca-df5e12af8ecde428.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@04bb837d6e7745d29b1272519fe8b0fe-000000000000086d-0005b8dfc382dc9d.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@074b853470b340ed951b78b9deb8dc71-000000000002a9f5-0005bb17e526fdcd.journal
7659ff0: Unused data (entry_offset==0)                                                                                                   
7659ff0: Invalid hash (00000000 vs. 581648e3c96b4e3a                                                                                     
7659ff0: Invalid object contents: Bad message                                                                                            
File corruption detected at /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005bab57c3d3b6a-43305ded593a7a9e.journal~:7659ff0 (of 125829120 bytes, 98%).
FAIL: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005bab57c3d3b6a-43305ded593a7a9e.journal~ (Bad message)
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@3a879b45ee0d40f28e9de821dfc83a01-0000000000000001-0005b8f3d2d4cd15.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@3a879b45ee0d40f28e9de821dfc83a01-00000000000c14ec-0005b9a40d37cff7.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@7958ba53b52f476bbb0181d7aa31b4a8-0000000000011724-0005b7ad4c94c785.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@c9eb907d55864799b9c237f317840e83-0000000000000001-0005bb159f481fe8.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005ba8c83627fe4-7a61cb41d9ce6c04.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005b8f2471ed402-353dcd308df37079.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005b83d457ff71c-51068c47ef338906.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@286cc890bd5149b1b15340f84aadaec0-000000000000089b-0005b8b7c85ccb47.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@2be0bd7baaa9496c8c44a16e4a842995-00000000000c2836-0005b9aecd7ab217.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@1dbba780c9744ca58543eee0a9a3456e-0000000000000959-0005b83d48dd78ff.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@2ede8f2bd7aa4cfd8dd778b0deb4e8d3-0000000000000001-0005ba33956f862f.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@42e260fe32174af6af1f378dcabb2097-0000000000078fe0-0005b8973aca3e00.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@7958ba53b52f476bbb0181d7aa31b4a8-000000000003898d-0005b81507b484a6.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@3a879b45ee0d40f28e9de821dfc83a01-00000000000b30e2-0005b97aded6a11d.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@3a879b45ee0d40f28e9de821dfc83a01-00000000000a2061-0005b969ca753312.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-000000000000dfdb-0005b720f9f2d290.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005b8f2061a56ae-e4b05324aa417fcf.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@6e73a3a505274fc39b372343f22a0d1a-000000000000bbd8-0005bafa834570d6.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@5f8a71e177af44a4a05a4d4203750a5d-00000000000b310b-0005b97b106ef507.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-0000000000005f13-0005b6b16a1add0c.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@7958ba53b52f476bbb0181d7aa31b4a8-00000000000103e6-0005b79a70fda85d.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@d5ece2d6e0d94390be6d80935b87fa4e-000000000000091c-0005bae6dc965040.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-000000000000a1da-0005b6d01f73be5c.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@42e260fe32174af6af1f378dcabb2097-0000000000000001-0005b83d457efb98.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@9c9c5c41e9134898961b8fe4ea85bc58-0000000000000001-0005b8dfc00d70a0.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@27e24dfcedc547b2856b50ef59c53f24-000000000002d9eb-0005b91a8a9124ef.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-00000000000008bc-0005b69ec4fffabf.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@631c5f278b2a4d4b8a2a11a41bc301c8-000000000007c086-0005b95f94efab9e.journal
7ffff58: Unused data (entry_offset==0)                                                                                                   
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@3a879b45ee0d40f28e9de821dfc83a01-000000000004d014-0005b9408290e7e4.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@2be0bd7baaa9496c8c44a16e4a842995-00000000000c1504-0005b9a418d98034.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005ba9ca4e96cf3-d80e004cb31c3150.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000.journal                                                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@7b9b29e73cfd4999b38b777b598549d7-0000000000000001-0005bae6da4939a0.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@7958ba53b52f476bbb0181d7aa31b4a8-000000000000b1d7-0005b6e56680883b.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005ba9ca325f9c5-73b73f9e71aa46cd.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@8e0b6f7a6dd34d6ea7dcd63742b004a5-0000000000000001-0005bb158d8d59f7.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005bae6da4a376f-e5d7e759f9da59ec.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@add63a63335d45e182ff51be690ab615-0000000000000869-0005ba3396e184f3.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005b83d48dd8376-bcf62e2bf0717367.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005baae9d60c5dd-7d241ab038f6af39.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005bb15a460f629-2cc152f465df036f.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@7958ba53b52f476bbb0181d7aa31b4a8-0000000000008057-0005b6b8c6745395.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005b8dfc382e9d7-1dc575cc50929f58.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system.journal                                                                   
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005ba3395708a2f-7c6890e6348dfa04.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@42e260fe32174af6af1f378dcabb2097-000000000002c4f1-0005b8786c16d598.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-000000000001173a-0005b7ad4ca64b69.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-00000000000103e9-0005b79a79c4e3ee.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@4ab51d32cc444292b77b69b1bfc0c7b3-0000000000000001-0005b8d2c57de350.journal
3589018: Invalid object                                                                                                                  
File corruption detected at /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005baae9affc3ff-d074b923c72fe44d.journal~:3589018 (of 58720256 bytes, 95%).
FAIL: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005baae9affc3ff-d074b923c72fe44d.journal~ (Bad message)
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@074b853470b340ed951b78b9deb8dc71-00000000000008b6-0005bb15a460e8b2.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@1dbba780c9744ca58543eee0a9a3456e-00000000000798b2-0005b8974140716c.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@1dbba780c9744ca58543eee0a9a3456e-0000000000052f26-0005b88d37d3001b.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@3a879b45ee0d40f28e9de821dfc83a01-00000000000d08f7-0005b9b75105a38a.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-0000000000038c18-0005b815096ac834.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-0000000000006efc-0005b6b2d5e0b6e0.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@42e260fe32174af6af1f378dcabb2097-0000000000052d8a-0005b88d3668df3a.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005ba86b96bbf50-13eb5f19ac851622.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@42e260fe32174af6af1f378dcabb2097-00000000000113f7-0005b84ee41bb762.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@7958ba53b52f476bbb0181d7aa31b4a8-000000000000dfd8-0005b720f9d03d2d.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@8b5a94f2c20b4adf87b9f8d59c113e67-0000000000000001-0005baae9afe82b1.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005b8f3d2d5d367-9734da333f9d214b.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005baef8cca998a-4ebb4aaf39509b07.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-000000000000b1de-0005b6e566ca13af.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005bb2c4921eb14-82a9b08b26f71a6e.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-0000000000012817-0005b812859fbcc1.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@3a879b45ee0d40f28e9de821dfc83a01-000000000007bb0f-0005b95f906b038f.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@1dbba780c9744ca58543eee0a9a3456e-000000000002c4f9-0005b8786c3d5cd4.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@7958ba53b52f476bbb0181d7aa31b4a8-000000000000a1c3-0005b6d01f68b242.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005b8f20b9718f0-64475c5bbd3d6d8e.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@1dbba780c9744ca58543eee0a9a3456e-0000000000011404-0005b84ee43c0609.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005ba9af166a96a-9de0c9d1b1d198fa.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005ba3396e192e9-ebe459a0bd3e622d.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005bb159f4943b5-a8ba853c76f96d13.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@631c5f278b2a4d4b8a2a11a41bc301c8-000000000004d02b-0005b94083690e54.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@0005bae6dc966143-084293e23ea880b5.journal~                             
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@27e24dfcedc547b2856b50ef59c53f24-000000000000085e-0005b8f3d4ba1f62.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005b8dfc00e651e-d982364f6d331331.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@8c6e06d92c5447f29783538231792c64-0000000000000001-0005baef88dcce97.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/system@0005b8d2c57ece8d-d7a06b5becf8c2ef.journal~                                
PASS: /var/log/journal/64f10889235b4d03ad83a8db73043969/user-1000@b4e3775e8f554a6c8527c3bb2739bd1b-000000000000807b-0005b6b8c6852d86.journal
```

Comment: `journalctl --verify` checks for corruption / errors in internal  journal log files not in the system. It does not necessarily mean there is something wrong with your system. These are log-files to keep track of things. I suggest you ask about actual problems you encounter in the system's functionality if there are any. Fixing the logs integrity is another issue and other than emptying the corrupted log files, I don't know of another way to fix them. But you don't seem to need to fix that as most of the logs look OK.